# Custom view measuring

Tags: android, view, android-view, android-custom-view

I have made a custom view - it extends `View`.  In the `onDraw()` method I create a circle with a set radius.  At the moment in my xml, I have the `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`.  The circle is the right size, but when I set an `onClickListener` I don't have to touch the circle for it to register. I can tap anywhere where there is no other view.

I think I need to do something with `onMeasure` or `LayoutParams` but I don't know what exactly.

The aim is for the `onClickListener` to only be called when I click the circle with the `layout_width` and `height` still being set to `wrap_content`.

EDIT:

This creates a square not a circle as I wanted.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() /2 , canvas.getHeight() /2,
                RADIUS, paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        widthMeasureSpec = RADIUS;
        heightMeasureSpec = RADIUS;

        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    }
```

Comment: `wrap_content` means to use the minimum dimensions which wrap the content of that view, so you need to tell android what those minimum dimensions are in the `onMeasure()` method.

Comment: @Luksprog So can I just make `widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec` equal the radius of my circle? EDIT: Yes, that works but it makes a sqaure...

Comment: Using the radius is a basic method for what you want but a View could receive some other constraints. A View is also a rectangle so you can't make it a circle or any other shape. You can however override it's `onTouch` method and trigger the click event only when the touch is registered in the area of the circle.

Comment: @Luksprog I understand the `onTouch()` part, but not the fact that I can't make my view circular. It was a nice circle before I set the dimensions.

Comment: I have added my code to show you. The output is a square not a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
float mTranslateX;
float mTranslateY;
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mTranslateX, mTranslateY);
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, RADIUS, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    final int dia = RADIUS * 2;
    int w = resolveSize(dia, widthMeasureSpec);
    int h = resolveSize(dia, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    float radius = Math.min(w, h)/2F;
    mTranslateX = radius;
    mTranslateY = radius;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but this still outputs as a -circle- square.

Comment: what exactly do you want then?

Comment: Sorry! I mean it still outputs as a square

Comment: I don't have compiler with me so please run and tell me what happens.

Comment: found one mistake ... wait

Comment: OK, I'll check in a few mins